# In Instagram Reel section no matter how hard we scroll we only jump to next 1st video, Can we implement something like that in Web? (HTML,CSS,JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

In Instagram or TikTok or any other short form video apps, we scroll just a little or hard the app only scrolls to next 1 video and if we scroll again then it scrolls to next 1 video.

So I was thinking can we implement something like that in Web with HTML CSS JS.

I try search it on Google but couldn't find any significant answer.

All the tutorials and articles shows one thing:

```
scroll-snap-type
```

property method. Well it works with small scroll but again it scrolls to next multiple pages when we scroll a little hard.

Comment: Don't actually make the page scroll. Listen for the scroll event and manually update the UI to the next or previous page.

Comment: Well that's a really interesting  approach. will definitely try this... Thanks for the help